# Dinamically created css grid does not return nodelist

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, dom

I've been trying to get a hold of a dinamically created html node list, but whenever I try to get the created nodes the list returns null. I am trying to use querySelectorAll() and then use a forEach to addEventListener to each button, so I can change the background color of each of them when the mouse passes of them. I've tried using the game as a querySelector instead of the document, but it does not work at all.

My HTML:

```
  <body>
    <main class="game-container">
      <h1>ETCH-A-SKETCH</h1>
      <div class="game-canvas" id="sketch-canvas"></div>
    </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
:root {
  --grid-cols: 1;
  --grid-rows: 1;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.game-container {
  padding: 1.25rem 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.game-canvas {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--grid-rows), 1fr);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--grid-cols), 1fr);
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 575px;
  width: 575px;
}
```

My javascript:

```
const game = document.getElementById("sketch-canvas");

function createGrid(rows, cols) {
  game.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  game.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);

  for (let i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.classList.add("grid-item");
    game.appendChild(span);
  }
}

const spans = document.querySelectorAll(".grid-item");
console.log(spans);
spans.forEach(span => {
span.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
  event.target.style.backgroundColor = random_rgba();
});

function random_rgba() {
  var o = Math.round,
    r = Math.random,
    s = 255;
  return (
    "rgba(" +
    o(r() * s) +
    "," +
    o(r() * s) +
    "," +
    o(r() * s) +
    "," +
    r().toFixed(1) +
    ")"
  );
}
```

Comment: You are adding the event listener before the element is created. Try adding the code related to the event listener inside of the `createGrid` function

Comment: @Rojo thank you very much! If you want to, submit this as the answer so I can give you the proper credits!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the event listener before the element is created. Try adding the code related to the event listener inside of the `createGrid` function:

```
function createGrid(rows, cols) {
  game.style.setProperty("--grid-rows", rows);
  game.style.setProperty("--grid-cols", cols);

  for (let i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
    const span = document.createElement("span");
    span.classList.add("grid-item");
    game.appendChild(span);
    span.addEventListener("mousedown", (event) => {
      event.target.style.backgroundColor = random_rgba();
    });
  }
}
```

Note that you don't even need `querySelectorAll` or `forEach`